# tvOS UITabBarController opaque zone

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, tvos

I have a strange issue with my tvOS app :

My app is presenting an UITabBar which is showing an UINavigationController with an UITableViewController as root view.

The problem is that I have a dark zone at the bottom of the screen (the top of the screen is also unusable but it's not really an issue for me) ! Anyone knows what could be the problem and how to make this zone available for my view ?
[image: UITabbar]

My setup code :

```
// Application launching
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

ServersListViewController *userAccountsViewController = [[ServersListViewController alloc] init];
self.serversNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:userAccountsViewController];
self.serversNavController.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Servers",nil);

NSArray *navControllersArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                self.serversNavController,
                                nil];
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = navControllersArray;

// Set root view controller
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```

note that if I replace last line with

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.serversNavController
```

I don't have the bottom opaque zone so issue seems related to UITabBarController (or with the way I build my view hierarchy).

The view descriptions if available here : http://pastebin.com/ZjyjG1in (not pasted here as it's too big ...)

Edit : it seems that the issue comes from the fact that I set a white background for my tableview ... When letting the translucent background, it looks better (even if bottom zone is still opaque). Maybe that playing with UITabBarController's background would allow to make bottom zone translucent but I didn't succeed ...
[image: Ok image]